# Mod_pagespeed with Zend Framework gives 404

Tags: apache-2.2, php, zend-framework, mod-pagespeed

I am expiering some problems with the Google's Apache mod_pagespeed module to combine css, js, etc. During the last months I developed a new version of our software based on Zend Framework. I just installed mod_pagespeed and it doesn't seem to work.

I run Ubuntu Server 11.04 and the latest mod_pagespeed module. I am using Zend Framework 1.11.11 and running PHP 5.3.3 with Apache 2.

When I put my Apache LogLevel to 'debug' then I get the following messages:

```
[Mon Jul 16 10:44:53 2012] [debug] net/instaweb/apache/mod_instaweb.cc(370): [client 217.196.45.116] ModPagespeed OutputFilter called for request /index.php
[Mon Jul 16 10:44:53 2012] [debug] net/instaweb/apache/mod_instaweb.cc(391): [client 217.196.45.116] Request not rewritten because: request->status != 200 (was 404)
```

When accessing a URL like: http://development.domain.nl/filter/fietsslot-1967/

I get the above errors. This might be caused I rewrite all calls to index.php as advised by Zend Framework:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|js|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

Header unset ETag
```

So it looks like mod_pagespeed makes an 'underlying' call to the same page but not with the original URL but the resolved version.

If I go to this URL: http://development.domain.nl/index.php

I get indeed an 404 because Zend Framework doesn't know what to do (which controller/action is accessed).

What should I do? Thanks in advance!

My Mod_Pagespeed configuration:

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    # Turn on mod_pagespeed. To completely disable mod_pagespeed, you
    # can set this to "off".
    ModPagespeed on

    # Direct Apache to send all HTML output to the mod_pagespeed
    # output handler.
    AddOutputFilterByType MOD_PAGESPEED_OUTPUT_FILTER text/html

    # If you want mod_pagespeed process XHTML as well, please uncomment this
    # line.
    # AddOutputFilterByType MOD_PAGESPEED_OUTPUT_FILTER application/xhtml+xml

    # The ModPagespeedFileCachePath and
    # ModPagespeedGeneratedFilePrefix directories must exist and be
    # writable by the apache user (as specified by the User
    # directive).
    ModPagespeedFileCachePath            "/var/mod_pagespeed/cache/"
    ModPagespeedGeneratedFilePrefix      "/var/mod_pagespeed/files/"

    # Override the mod_pagespeed 'rewrite level'. The default level
    # "CoreFilters" uses a set of rewrite filters that are generally
    # safe for most web pages. Most sites should not need to change
    # this value and can instead fine-tune the configuration using the
    # ModPagespeedDisableFilters and ModPagespeedEnableFilters
    # directives, below. Valid values for ModPagespeedRewriteLevel are
    # PassThrough, CoreFilters and TestingCoreFilters.
    #
    # ModPagespeedRewriteLevel PassThrough

    # Explicitly disables specific filters. This is useful in
    # conjuction with ModPagespeedRewriteLevel. For instance, if one
    # of the filters in the CoreFilters needs to be disabled for a
    # site, that filter can be added to
    # ModPagespeedDisableFilters. This directive contains a
    # comma-separated list of filter names, and can be repeated.
    #
    # ModPagespeedDisableFilters rewrite_images

    # Explicitly enables specific filters. This is useful in
    # conjuction with ModPagespeedRewriteLevel. For instance, filters
    # not included in the CoreFilters may be enabled using this
    # directive. This directive contains a comma-separated list of
    # filter names, and can be repeated.
    #
    # ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_javascript,rewrite_css
    # ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace,elide_attributes

    ModPagespeedRewriteLevel CoreFilters

    ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters elide_attributes
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters extend_cache
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_css
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_javascript
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_css
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_javascript
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_images
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters remove_comments
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters insert_image_dimensions

    ModPagespeedDisallow */tiny_mce.js
    ModPagespeedDisallow */munin/*


    # ModPagespeedDomain
    # authorizes rewriting of JS, CSS, and Image files found in this
    # domain. By default only resources with the same origin as the
    # HTML file are rewritten. For example:
    #
    #   ModPagespeedDomain cdn.myhost.com
    #
    # This will allow resources found on http://cdn.myhost.com to be
    # rewritten in addition to those in the same domain as the HTML.
    #
    # Wildcards (* and ?) are allowed in the domain specification. Be
    # careful when using them as if you rewrite domains that do not
    # send you traffic, then the site receiving the traffic will not
    # know how to serve the rewritten content.

    # Other defaults (cache sizes and thresholds):
    #
    # ModPagespeedFileCacheSizeKb          102400
    # ModPagespeedFileCacheCleanIntervalMs 3600000
    # ModPagespeedLRUCacheKbPerProcess     1024
    # ModPagespeedLRUCacheByteLimit        16384
    # ModPagespeedCssInlineMaxBytes        2048
    # ModPagespeedImageInlineMaxBytes      2048
    # ModPagespeedCssImageInlineMaxBytes   2048
    # ModPagespeedJsInlineMaxBytes         2048
    # ModPagespeedCssOutlineMinBytes       3000
    # ModPagespeedJsOutlineMinBytes        3000

    # Bound the number of images that can be rewritten at any one time; this
    # avoids overloading the CPU.  Set this to 0 to remove the bound.
    #
    # ModPagespeedImageMaxRewritesAtOnce      8

    # You can also customize the number of threads per Apache process
    # mod_pagespeed will use to do resource optimization. Plain
    # "rewrite threads" are used to do short, latency-sensitive work,
    # while "expensive rewrite threads" are used for actual optimization
    # work that's more computationally expensive. If you live these unset,
    # or use values <= 0 the defaults will be used, which is 1 for both
    # values when using non-threaded MPMs (e.g. prefork) and 4 for both
    # on threaded MPMs (e.g. worker and event). These settings can only
    # be changed globally, and not per virtual host.
    #
    # ModPagespeedNumRewriteThreads 4
    # ModPagespeedNumExpensiveRewriteThreads 4


    # Settings for image optimization:
    #
    # Jpeg recompression quality (0 to 100, -1 strips metadata):
    # ModPagespeedJpegRecompressionQuality -1
    #
    # Percent of original image size below which optimized images are retained:
    # ModPagespeedImageLimitOptimizedPercent 100
    #
    # Percent of original image area below which image resizing will be
    # attempted:
    # ModPagespeedImageLimitResizeAreaPercent 100

    # When Apache is set up as a browser proxy, mod_pagespeed can record
    # web-sites as they are requested, so that an image of the web is built up
    # in the directory of the proxy administrator's choosing.  When ReadOnly is
    # on, only files already present in the SlurpDirectory are served by the
    # proxy.
    #
    # ModPagespeedSlurpDirectory ...
    # ModPagespeedSlurpReadOnly on

    # The maximum URL size is generally limited to about 2k characters
    # due to IE: See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427/EN-US.
    # Apache servers by default impose a further limitation of about
    # 250 characters per URL segment (text between slashes).
    # mod_pagespeed circumvents this limitation, but if you employ
    # proxy servers in your path you may need to re-impose it by
    # overriding the setting here.  The default setting is 1024
    # characters.
    #
    # ModPagespeedMaxSegmentLength 250

    # Uncomment this if you want to prevent mod_pagespeed from combining files
    # (e.g. CSS files) across paths
    #
    # ModPagespeedCombineAcrossPaths off

    # Renaming JavaScript URLs can sometimes break them.  With this
    # option enabled, mod_pagespeed uses a simple heuristic to decide
    # not to rename JavaScript that it thinks is introspective.
    #
    # You can turn this off to let mod_pagespeed rename all JS files.
    ModPagespeedAvoidRenamingIntrospectiveJavascript on

    # Explicitly tell mod_pagespeed to load some resources from disk.
    # This will speed up load time and update frequency.
    #
    # This should only be used for static resources which do not need
    # specific headers set or other processing by Apache.
    #
    # Both URL and filesystem path should specify directories and
    # filesystem path must be absolute (for now).
    #
    # ModPagespeedLoadFromFile "http://example.com/static/" "/var/www/static/"


    # Enables server-side instrumentation and statistics.  If this rewriter is
    # enabled, then each rewritten HTML page will have instrumentation javacript
    # added that sends latency beacons to /mod_pagespeed_beacon.  These
    # statistics can be accessed at /mod_pagespeed_statistics.  You must also
    # enable the mod_pagespeed_statistics and mod_pagespeed_beacon handlers
    # below.
    #
    # ModPagespeedEnableFilters add_instrumentation

    # The add_instrumentation filter sends a beacon after the page onload
    # handler is called. The user might navigate to a new URL before this. If
    # you enable the following directive, the beacon is sent as part of an
    # onbeforeunload handler, for pages where navigation happens before the
    # onload event.
    #
    # ModPagespeedReportUnloadTime on

    # Uncomment the following line so that ModPagespeed will not cache or
    # rewrite resources with Vary: in the header, e.g. Vary: User-Agent.
    # ModPagespeedRespectVary on

    # This handles the client-side instrumentation callbacks which are injected
    # by the add_instrumentation filter.
    # You can use a different location by adding the ModPagespeedBeaconUrl
    # directive; see the documentation on add_instrumentation.
    <Location /mod_pagespeed_beacon>
      SetHandler mod_pagespeed_beacon
    </Location>

    # Uncomment the following line if you want to disable statistics entirely.
    #
    # ModPagespeedStatistics off

    # This page lets you view statistics about the mod_pagespeed module.
    <Location /mod_pagespeed_statistics>
    Order allow,deny
    # You may insert other "Allow from" lines to add hosts you want to
    # allow to look at generated statistics.  Another possibility is
    # to comment out the "Order" and "Allow" options from the config
    # file, to allow any client that can reach your server to examine
    # statistics.  This might be appropriate in an experimental setup or
    # if the Apache server is protected by a reverse proxy that will
    # filter URLs in some fashion.
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from 217.196.45.116 #TMG
    SetHandler mod_pagespeed_statistics
    </Location>

    # Page /mod_pagespeed_message lets you view the latest messages from
    # mod_pagespeed, regardless of log-level in your httpd.conf
    # ModPagespeedMessageBufferSize is the maximum number of bytes you would
    # like to dump to your /mod_pagespeed_message page at one time,
    # its default value is 100k bytes.
    # Set it to 0 if you want to disable this feature.
    ModPagespeedMessageBufferSize 100000

    <Location /mod_pagespeed_message>
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from 217.196.45.116 #TMG
    SetHandler mod_pagespeed_message
    </Location>
    <Location /mod_pagespeed_referer_statistics>
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from 217.196.45.116 #TMG
    SetHandler mod_pagespeed_referer_statistics
    </Location>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Which mod_pagespeed filters do you have enabled? Are you sure they are not working?

Comment: Check my configuration, and yes, css/js is nog combined or minified..

Comment: Seems that this problem is discusssed here either: http://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/detail?id=419#makechanges mapping the url like: index.php?path=$0 would be a solution but I rather like to fix it how it should work by default.